# What are the advantages of using fstat() vs stat()?

Tags: c, file, system-calls, stat, fstat

If I have an open file with a known file descriptor, what are the advantages of using `fstat()`, versus `stat()`? Why isn't there only one function?

```
int fstat(int fildes, struct stat *buf)

int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf)
```

Comment: If the process related to the file descriptor we can use fstat(),if the name is available then we can use stat().

Comment: Based on the working process it may use ,for example you have open the file with file descriptor that time use fstat() .But if the file not opened then you can use stat() .That is the different .

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As noted, `stat()` works on filenames, while `fstat()` works on file descriptors.

Why have two functions for that?

One factor is likely to be convenience. It's just nice to be able to `fstat()` a file descriptor that you obtained from other parts of your code, without having to pass the filename too.

The major reason is security, though. If you first `stat()` the file and then `open()` it, there is a small window of time in between where the file could have been modified (or had its permissions changed, etc) or replaced with a symlink.

`fstat()` avoids that problem. You first `open()` the file, then the file can't be swapped out beneath your feet any more. Then you `fstat()` and you can be sure that you have the right file.

Answer (score 6):

`fstat` is to be used with a file descriptor obtained via the `open` call. Its main feature is to get information on already opened file descriptors instead of reopening.

You can also use `fstat` with `FILE` handlers like so (error handling omitted):

```cpp
FILE *fp = fopen("/path/to/file", "r");
struct stat st;
fstat(fileno(fp), &st);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file descriptor, you do not necessarily know the path (e.g. when the file was opened by some other part of your application).

If you know the path, you do not need to call `open` to get a file descriptor just for the purpose of calling `fstat`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `man fstat`, you will see the following:

> fstat() is identical to stat(), except that the file to be stat-ed is
>   specified by the file descriptor fd.

To expand a little bit, you would use `fstat` if you happened to have a file descriptor instead of a file path.

With respect to information provided by the function, they are literally identical, as you can see from the above quote.

Comment: So if I know the path, but I know the file descriptor aswell, which one should I choose?

Comment: Pick whichever you like. If you are concerned about performance, then benchmark both and see which runs faster for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a file descriptor to a file (but you may not know its path), then you could use `fstat()`; if you only have a path to a file, then you could use `stat()` directly, no need to open it first.